# Issues with import in ACL

Tags: acl, civicrm-spark

I have turned off `CiviCRM: import contacts` but the user still has the option to import contacts and activities? Using CiviSpark with version CiviCRM 5.68.1. Unable to update to the latest version.

[image: settings/ACLS]
[image: menu]
[image: import screen]

Comment: Welcome @Russell! Can you please edit your question to indicate the version of CiviCRM you're using?  It should be in the footer of all CiviCRM backend pages.